# iptables drop all incoming ICMP requests except from one IP

Tags: linux, iptables

Currently, I have something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

However, when I run the second command, it looks as if iptables just stops.  I have to break out of it to get back to terminal.  Perhaps I am doing it all wrong, but some insight would be helpful.

Comment: You also need to flip it so that the the ACCEPT is first, or change `-A` to `-I`

Comment: @Patrick when I do that, it seems as if it quits out at the start and doesn't write the rule.

Comment: your first rule will have to come last if you look at `iptables -L -nv` and check out the counters when you're testing your rules you'll find out it's probably incrementing dropping the packets never reaching your other rule.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to run your rules in the opposite order. Iptables is sensitive to the order that commands were run. If a rule matches, it doesn't go on to check more rules, it just obeys that one. If you set the drop first, the accept rule will never get tested. By setting the specific accept with the source IP, then setting the more general policy to drop you will affect the expected behavior.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

As for the hang problem you seem to be having, are you sure you entered a valid IP address? Perhaps you can prefix that command with `strace iptables …` to see what it's doing while it appears to hang.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  Looks like this was happening with another ruleset also, causing it to hang!

Answer (score 3):

Do not drop ICMP willy-nilly! Sure, some of the ICMP requests are dangerous, but the rest is absolutely required for the network to work (think "destination unreachable" and that zoo).

Comment: ICMP is not required for a network to function.

Comment: icmp filtering breaks MTU discovery soo good luck trying to use jumbo frames without functioning icmp !

Answer (score -2):

You will have to add a rule like:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it did the same thing -- to no avail.

Comment: you run those command in that order??? Rules in iptables , As far as i concern, are execute from botton to top

Comment: This is just an alternate syntax for the rule the OP was already running.